# Array to List -- Cannot make AddRange(IEnumerable) work

Tags: c#, arrays, .net-3.5, list

I'm sorry about the naive question. I have the following:

```
public Array Values
{
  get;
  set;
}

public List<object> CategoriesToList()
{
  List<object> vals = new List<object>();
  vals.AddRange(this.Values);

    return vals;
}
```

But this won't work because I can't type the array. Is there any way to easily fix the code above or, in general, convert System.Collections.Array to System.Collections.Generic.List?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you're `using System.Linq;` and then change your line to:

`vals.AddRange(this.Values.Cast<object>());`

Edit: You could also iterate over the array and add each item individually.

Edit Again: Yet another option to simply cast your array as `object[]` and either use the `ToList()` function or pass it into the `List<object>` constructor:

`((object[])this.Values).ToList();`

or

`new List<object>((object[])this.Values)`

Comment: I didn't really want to use Linq for this, but thank you. This is pretty. You deserve acceptance :)

Answer (score 2):

Can you just change your property declaration to this? :

```
public object[] Values { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hi. No, I can't. I'm getting the array from the old Word 2003 API. Unless I'm missing another obvious thing... :(

Comment: No - problem.  I took another look at it.

Answer (score 0):

using System.Linq;
...

```
    public object[] Values
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<object> CategoriesToList()
    {
        List<object> vals = new List<object>();
        vals.AddRange(Values.ToList());

        return vals;
    }
```

Comment: You can actually just pass in `Values` as is since `object[]` is an IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use linq you can simply cast:

```
vals.AddRange((IEnumerable<object>) this.Values);
```